# paypal Payment gateway link for direct payment

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

hear is my code for paypal payment it redirects to login of paypal gateway,
but i want it redirect to direct payment page so that if i haven't paypal account 
i can countinue with that option.

```
<?php
    $paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    $paypal_id = 'gohilpriyank-facilitator@ymail.com';
    ?>
    <div class="form-group row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Ship To Address:-</span>
            <div><?php echo $ship_to['ship_address']; ?></div>
            <div><?php echo $ship_to['ship_landmark']; ?></div>
            <div><?php echo $ship_to['ship_city']; ?></div>
            <div><?php echo $ship_to['ship_state']; ?></div>
            <div><?php echo $ship_to['ship_pincode']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Choose Payment Mode</span>
            <form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Kevalam Payment">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo count($this->cart->contents()); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">
                <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['grand_total']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://k1-pc/myriad/assets/user_temp/image/logo.png">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://k1-pc/myriad/cancel.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://k1-pc/myriad/success.php">

                <input type="image" src="https://paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit">
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div><div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Payments Standard like this the Guest Checkout (direct credit card) option is displayed differently based on the cookies set for the current browser.

If you've ever signed in to any PayPal with the same browser it will find a cookie and assume that you'll be signing in again, so it will show you a landing page that really pushes the login aspect of PayPal checkout.

If you clear your browser cache/cookies (or just try a fresh browser) you should see a different landing page where the Guest Checkout option is more prominently displayed.

If you switch to the Express Checkout API instead of using Payments Standard you can force Guest Checkout to be displayed more prominently regardless of browser cookies.  The SetExpressCheckout request includes parameters you can use to adjust the checkout pages accordingly.

Since you're using PHP, I'd recommend taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It would make integrating Express Checkout very simple for you.  Basically, it consists of the following API calls, which are included in the /templates directory with the library.

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/templates/SetExpressCheckout.php)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/templates/GetExpressCheckoutDetails.php)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/templates/DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php)

The parameters you'll use to handle the Guest Checkout options are in the SetExpressCheckout request and consist of...

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Comment: Thanks for this support,